# БД для единого аккаунта

Tags: база-данных, проектирование

Есть идея создать проект, который состоит из разных веб-приложений, со своей тематикой и ещё отдельное веб-приложение для единой авторизации. То есть хочу создать единый профиль для всех приложений, с единой точкой входа. Но упёрся в проектирование БД. Я пришёл к тому, что для сервиса авторизации нужна отдельная БД с основной информацией аккаунта (пароль, почта и т. д.) и по БД для каждого из веб-приложений, так как информация в них будет своя, контент пересекаться не будет. Например, как сделала материнская компания Хабра, один аккаунт, но разные продукты, со своим наполнением. Но не знаю, в правильную сторону я думаю или нет. Может нужно слить всё в одну БД, но не думаю что это логично.

Помогите, пожалуйста, советом, как строить такую систему. Или просто подскажите как загуглить этот вопрос, так как я никак не могу найти что-то по этой теме.

Comment: Я бы гугловскую Firebase прикрутил. Там уже реализован вход через смс и уведомления и ещё разные плюшки